# Find the real roots

Tags: numerical-methods

I have the following equation:
\begin{equation}
 (y-1)^a - C~~ y~~ \exp(b x)=0
\end{equation}

where $a, b$ are real constants, $C$ may be a complex number. I need to find the real solution of the above equation for each choice of $x$, with $x \in [-100, 100]$. I tried with $\mathbf{fzero, fsolve}$ in matlab. But it does not work. I also tried to solve with Newto - Raphson method. The outcome is negative.

Is it possible to solve it in some other way. Any help/suggestion/advice,  will be  very useful. Thanks.

Comment: What's $y$?${}{}$

Comment: $y$ is the unknown variable. For each fixed choice of constants $a, b, C$ and varying $x \in [-100, 100]$, I need to find the values of $y$.